# Ajax POST not working on a mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, post

Please guide me on how make this javascript code work on mobile device.

I have tested on a desktop browser and its working fine.

But in Android device 4.1.2 can't post submit

```js
$(function () {
$i.ajax ({
  type: "POST",
  url: web,
  crossDomain: true,
  data: dataString,
  context: document.body,
  cache: false,
  beforeSend: function(html) {
        document.getElementById("hasil").innerHTML = '';
        $i(".flash").show();
        $i(".flash").html('<div style="float:left;"></div>');
  },
  success: function(html){
    $i("#js_process_request input, #js_process_request select").attr('disabled',false);
    $i(".flash").hide();
    $i("#hasil").hide();
    $i("#hasil").append(html);   
  }
```

Comment: what code? do you want to find help with

Comment: sorry foreget  it :)

Comment: did you try it on any other phone?

Comment: yes..but cant post ajax..